# Species-area relation graph

Tags: ecology, biodiversity

When species richness is plotted vs area, the graph follows the equation : log S = log C + Z log A where Z is the slope of the line. Z values are usually in the range of 0.1 to 0.2 but if very large areas like entire continents are analyzed, the slope is much steeper. (0.6-1.2).

Why is it so ?

(Here S = species richness and A= area under consideration)

Comment: Interesting question. Can you please add some reference and eventually two graphs that show different slope depending on the range of areas used? Note also that if $C$ designates a constant (which I think it does), then $log C$ is a constant too and could well just be replaced by $K$ (or just write $C$). You should also make clear that $S$ is species richness and $A$ is the area even though it is quite intuitive.

Comment: @Remi.b The full log notation is useful to highlight that the basic relationship is a power law: $S = CA^z$

Comment: Perhaps because when analyzing large areas, adjacent masses of considerably different climatic conditions are successively bought under analysis, and will hence increase the richness faster than compared to small areas where increasing the analyzed area is still more likely to be confined to the same geo-climatic zone. Just speculations, though. Will get back with a better answer.

Comment: Right, @Satwik Pasana. Also consider that evolutionary history becomes increasingly important when you're looking at large areas.

Comment: @satwik pasani That makes sense. Actually when I had asked the question I had a wrong notion of what species richness is but now what you say seems logical. Add it as an answer !

Comment: @Hav0k Could you elaborate a bit ? Do you mean to say that larger the area, more are the chances that a larger no of species would have evolved in it ?

Comment: Well, not exactly. I meant that when you increase area, at some point you will likely add regions that share different evolutionary histories and thus add disproportionally more species, thereby increasing z. Imagine you start with a small area in North America and increase its size until it encompasses all of NA. Now there is no more area in NA to add, so you start adding parts of South America. These species assemblages differ drastically from North American ones and even small increases in area will yield many new species --> your z increases.

Comment: @hav0k ok yes. That is a really good explanation too.

Comment: What are the data points in the relationship you are thinking about (the "samples")? The number of species vs area for each continent or species richness vs area for subsamples ( or nested samples?) taken at the continent level? Relatively often, slopes of mainland areas or well-connected islands are smaller than slopes for more isolated island groups.

Comment: @fileunderwater species richness vs samples of increasing area

Comment: Either way, you should add a reference to back up your basic claim (steeper slopes for continent-level samples).

Comment: @biogirl Also, what taxa are you considering? To me, it is still also unclear whether you are asking about a species-area relationship where the data points are entire continents, or large-scale species-area relationships within continents (nested or otherwise).

Comment: @fileunderwater My question is just a general one. I am asking about large scale species area relations within continents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z value is a fitted constant and it ranges between 0.1 to 0.3 regardless  of the region or taxonomic groups.i.e. the slope is almost similar .Among larger areas like continent,the slope tends to be much steeper.becoz, Larger the area larger will be number of species(species richness),for larger areas the Z values tends to be 0.6 to 1.2.(NOTE:if Z is less,lesser area is enough to capture more species).